# Assignment in python getting weirded

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have posted code:

```
"""
Inputs:
objective: guess -> Double; provides a score of the candidate solutions
initial_sol: guess; the first guess
initial_temp: Double
perturb: guess -> guess; make a change to a candidate solution by moving to an element in the neighbourhood
temperature_trans: Double -> Double; should be strictly decreasing.  Used to reduce temperature in the model.
stop_temp: Double; Temperature at which the model is considered "cold"
stop_cond: [Double] -> Bool; used as an alternative way to stop -- examines the record of fitnesses to check if they are cool as in not getting better
equilibrium_max: Int; Used to control the maximum number of inner iterations performed.
equilibrium: (Double,[Double]) -> Bool; used to determine equilibrium of the inner model based on temperature and fitness level.  Allows adjusting
                                        the number of times the inner loop is performed based on the temperature and equilibrium (so at low temps we can 
                                        explore more)
"""
def simulated_annealing_homogenous(objective, initial_sol, initial_temp, perturb, temperature_transition, stop_temp, stop_cond, equilibrium_max, equilibrium):
    current_solution = initial_sol
    best_seen = initial_sol  # used to collect the best seen from a temperature, or to reset.
    temp = initial_temp
    current_fitness = objective(current_solution)
    best_fitness = current_fitness
    fitnesses = []
    while ((temp >= stop_temp) & (not(stop_cond(fitnesses)))):
        inner_loop_count = 0
        while ((inner_loop_count < equilibrium_max) & (not(equilibrium(temp, fitnesses)))):
            new_sol = perturb(current_solution)
            new_fitness = objective(new_sol)
            delta = new_fitness - current_fitness
            u = random.random()
            if delta < 0:
                accept = True
            elif (u <= math.exp(-delta / temp)):
                accept = True
            else:
                accept = False
            if accept:
                current_solution = new_sol
                current_fitness = new_fitness
                if current_fitness < best_fitness:
                    best_seen = current_solution
                    best_fitness = current_fitness
                fitnesses.append(current_fitness)
            inner_loop_count += 1
        temp = temperature_transition(temp)
    return best_seen
```

I was trying to write a very simple simulated annealing algorithm in Python.  Let me abstract out what I wanted to do.

```
  best = initial
  while (not cold):
    while (not equilibrium):
      bunch of stuff
      if current is better than best:
        best = current
      some stuff
  return best
```

I was getting "wrong" answers in the following sense.  I added tracing (ahem .. print statements) to my code to see the values it was producing on some sample problems.  I noticed that the fitness was converging on all problems.  Indeed if I return current, instead of best, I would get a good solution.  Next, decided to print the values of "best" inside the while loop.  While in the loop, I printed the value of best, every time it changed.  You could clearly see best converge.  However, the final answer it returned wasn't the one from the last time it was updated.  So I must be doing something wrong.
It feels like the assignment is betting weirded out.  But it's probably user error.

Note, this is a first project for me in python.

Comment: Is the conditional for either while loop letting it run *one-extra-time*? Sometimes getting a while loop conditional right is tricky.

Comment: If I read that correctly, your best solution is the one that produces a minimum fitness value AND meets the criteria ```delta < 0 or u <= math.exp(-delta / temp)```.  How large is the search space - is it practical to accumulate all the solutions (and their fitnesses) then pick the minimum?

Comment: So with this algorithm, it wouldn't matter if it was running for more loops.  The idea is that the longer you run, as the temperature decreases, the better the answer gets.  We can't know how long it will take to get an optimal solution, so we impose some stopping condition.

Comment: For your second comment, let me try to explain.  So you start at some random point on a search "surface"  You want to find a low point in a valley somewhere on this surface.  So you take a random move (delta < 0).  If it puts you in a better place, then you make this your new location.  What about if the random move didn't put you in a better place?  You could just stay put.  This is called a hill-climber.  This algorithm is very prone to getting stuck in local minimums.  So what you do is, you allow to make a bad move (note that in the elif, delta >= 0) with some small probability.

Comment: The longer you run the algorithm for, the less likely you are to accept a solution that is worse.  I think it is recommend to use a starting temperature that accepts bad move with probability > 1/2 at first, and the more slowly you cool, the better solutions you are likely to get.  I think there are some results that if you cool slowly enough, you will get the global minimum.

Comment: The inner `while` loop contains a syntax error: You can't have `&` and `not` directly following without disambiguating, because they have the same operator precedence. But one would use `and` instead of `&` here anyway.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I missed that as I had added the not just before posting, so that the code made more sense to read.  There *is* a parentheses around the expression in my code

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: Well the proper way would be to use `and`. Unless you actually need both sides to be evaluated _always_ or the operands have overloaded `&`.  But even then it's a bit confusing for most readers and should be documented _why_ you use `&`.

Comment: @BlackJack: Ah.  Thanks for the tip.  I didn't realize & was non-shortcircuiting.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, printing out values at specific points to see what they are. There's nothing wrong with, ahem, print statements if you know what you're doing :-)

The only thing you *may* have wrong is what you're printing out.

Since you only update the "best" solution (seen and fitness) where `accept` is true, you probably want to print that out as well. It could be that solutions aren't being checked because of the `delta` value.

In code as complex as this, I either step through it with a debugger, or basically put a `print` statement between every line, outputting what could have been changed by that line.

Then I walk through the code and debug output line by line to see what's happening.

As a first attempt, you could simply print out `delta` and `temp` when `accept` is set to false, and print out `current`, `best` and `new` values immediately before the final `if` in your code.

---

One other thing to watch out for is that:

```
u = random.random()
```

is hardly conducive to a deterministic solution. At least in terms of debugging, you want a repeatable situation so that any tweaks you make to the code can be analysed properly rather than being made useless by the added injection of random data. For the debugging stage you may want to set `u` to a fixed value.

Comment: I know that best_seen is getting updated inside the while loop for a fact.  I used print statements inside the while-loop, to print best_seen and best_fitness, and I can watch the fitness value go down.  And you can see that the fitness value only decreases ... like it should.  But then, the value returned from the function turns out to be some other thing.

Comment: I checked the u=random.random() bit.  It isn't causing problems.  I set it to 0.2, so essentially after a certain number of iterations, the check it's used for is always false.

Comment: I have a feeling that something is modifying best_seen that shouldn't be, or that there is some scoping rule I am missing.  I can confirm that the value of best_seen is correct outside of that test condition in which it's modified.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a debugger to print every that variable is accessed and tell me all available information?  Such as the line in the source code that is doing the update?

Comment: @JonathanGallagher The standard library comes with `pdb` as text based debugger. Some IDEs have fancier debuggers. And there's [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/), a standalone (multi platform) GUI debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it is definitely a problem with assignment, and my understanding of assignment in python.  In python assignment means, copy a pointer (unless the value being assigned is a literal such as an int).  I should have been copying the values using copy or deepcopy.  The way I was doing it, initial, current, and best, were all sharing a copy of the same structure, in the case that mattered an array.  Thus, inside the inner loop, I would update

```
new_sol = perturb(current_solution)
```

new_sol, best, and current were all perturb(current_solution).  Now since the fitnesses are floats, they were different, so the tests would pass on occasion; giving me the illusion that the algorithm was searching (however, the algorithm with these semantics was nothing close to simulated annealing). Changing all array assignments to

```
a0 = copy.deepcopy(a1)
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: Assignment to a name always means the same. The difference lies within the objects, if they are mutable or not. Ints are not mutable. Lists for instance are. Instead of changing the assignments this way you should change the API of the functions.  Don't mutate _and_ return a passed object. Readers will be confused if you do. Because there is no reason to return an object that was passed into a function. The caller obviously already has that object, otherwise it could not have been passed.

Comment: @BlackJack: I have no idea what you mean.  I don't mutate and return an object that was passed in.  I need to use the initial_guess to make future guesses.  Even if I assume that the perturb function passed in by the user, returns a copy of whatever they worked with, the problem is that I still need to bind current and initial at some point. So break the binding by using copy.  The problem is that assignment is not bidirectional a = b setups a dependence on a for what b is.  So if b changes, so does a.  But if I change a, b does not change.

Comment: As I understood `perturb()` got an object, mutated it, and returned it, instead of creating a new mutated object and leaving the passed in object unchanged. As far as I see that's the only change needed. Having a ”real” function instead of a ”procedure” with an API that just suggests it's a function. And assignment is of course ”bidirectional”. After `a = b` both names stand for the exact same object. Any mutations can be made _and_ seen under both names — it's the identical object after all.

Comment: Well, I suppose that perturb wouldn't need to be a function.  I suppose one could just do perturb(current).  But I am used to Haskell, where all data is immutable, so I wouldn't have think this a good idea.  The name "perturb" just comes from the physical analogy.

Comment: My point is it needs to be a function in the functional programming/mathematical/Haskell sense but isn't. Otherwise you wouldn't have the problem.